# NOT EXISTS with several constant rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, constants, not-exists

Given a `Dictionary` table {`word_id`, `word`}.

`word` is char(32), `word_id` is int, IDENTITY and PRIMARY KEY.

I need to ensure some words exist in the `Dictionary` table. If they don't exist, those need to be added. I am having a hard time trying to wrap NOT EXISTS clause around several constant value.

Suppose the Dictionary has 3 entries:

```
test
test2
test3
```

I am trying to ensure words `test1`, `test2`, and `hello` are there. From those listed, only `test2` is in the database, so `test1` and `hello` need to be inserted. Here is the query I am currently stuck with, don't know how to reference the synthetic column (#1 in the UNION ALL result set):

```
INSERT INTO Dictionary (word)
SELECT 'test1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'hello'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Dictionary d WHERE d.word = {column1?})
```

Don't worry about SQL injection for now - in the real world app a set of words will be passed via a parameterized query. I am just trying to grasp the concept for now.

Comment: Have you tried using a temp table to store the comparison words and then using a "NOT IN(SELECT Word FROM Dictionary)" statement to do this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't think aliases can work in the WHERE clause. I would need a nested SELECT or CTE, trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), either by providing the column name in the expression:

```
WITH Data(Word) AS
(
  SELECT 'test1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test2'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'hello'
)
SELECT Word FROM Data
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Dictionary d 
                  WHERE d.Word = Data.Word)
```

or via alias in the query:

```
WITH Data AS
(
  SELECT Word = 'test1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Word = 'test2'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Word = 'hello'
)
SELECT Word FROM Data
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Dictionary d 
                  WHERE d.Word = Data.Word)
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! CTE is the winner today. I used your option #1, since it's the easiest to change from my existing code. +1 and accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You can warp the `UNION ALL` in another `SELECT`, give an alias to the word column, and put parentheses around the nested query, so that the `WHERE` clause applies to all rows of the union:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'test1' AS word
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'test2' AS word
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'hello' AS word
) ww
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Dictionary d WHERE d.word = ww.word)
```

Comment: Nothing shorter than that? This code will be composed programmatically, so that's why trying to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach that doesn't require the use of UNIONs. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE #WordCandidates([word] [char](32) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #WordCandidates VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO #WordCandidates VALUES ('test2');
INSERT INTO #WordCandidates VALUES ('hello');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Dictionary] ([word])
    SELECT word from #WordCandidates WHERE word NOT IN(SELECT [word] FROM [dbo].[Dictionary]    )

DROP TABLE #WordCandidates;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I feel that it won't work well when several users are adding words concurrently. You'd have to be creative about naming the temporary table etc., all of which adds complexity.